# Boolean algebra generated by value sets of polynomials over $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, boolean-algebra

Update

For each polynomial $P \in \mathbb{N}[X]$, let $S_P = \{ P(n) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Does 
the Boolean algebra generated by the subsets $S_P$ of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $P$ is a polynomial satisfying $P(0) = 0$ - contain a nonempty finite set?

Comment: Consider the polynomials $X+2$ and $X+1$.

Comment: @http://math.stackexchange.com/users/39174/hagen-von-eitzen Ooops, you right. I wanted only polynomials with $P(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The intersection of the sets of values of $x^2$ and $x^3+x$ is finite. This is because the elliptic curve
$$
y^2=x^3+x
$$
has only finitely many points with integer coordinates (IIRC this holds for all elliptic curves).

In this particular case we can also argue directly. As $x$ and $x^2+1$ are coprime,
their product is a square, if and only if they are both squares. The latter is obviously a square only if $x=0$.

Thus $S_{x^2}\cap S_{x^3+x}=\{0\}$.

If $0\notin\Bbb{N}$ for you, then $y^2=x^3+4x$ should also work and give you
$S_{x^2}\cap S_{x^3+4x}=\{(0),16\}.$

Comment: Just for some confirmation, there are only finitely many integral points on any elliptic curve, or more generally, only finitely many $\mathcal{O}_K$-points. This is due to Siegel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel's_theorem_on_integral_points :)